# When Refresh the browser previous data loading in gridview in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, browser-refresh

I have one asp.net page with two gridview using updatepanel.when i click the submit button data inserting in db and update the gridview. i'm handling duplicate insertion of same data when refresh the page. but the problem is when i refreshing the page  previous data in the gridview showing not present data. again if i'm clicking the menu its reloading and showing actual data.i'm handling button click but i don't know how to handle this gridview problem when i refresh the page. if anybody pass through same problem please show some light on this or please give some suggession.

Comment: Could you show your relevant `UpdatePanel` HTML code as well as your `Page_Load`?

Answer (score 0):

I would try:

```
gridviewObj.datasource = null
gridviewobj.datasource.databind();
```

... hope this helps

Comment: Suggestions of things to try aren't really answers. If you're sure this is the issue, then please provide an explanation and not just a code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

you could do this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    if (Page.IsPostBack)
    {
    //here you bind again the datagrid
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use if(IsPosback) in Page_Load event
then
 UpdatePanel.Update();